# Overloading operators for different states

Tags: python, operator-overloading

How can I overload operators for different states in Python? For example, look at the following C++ code:

```c
class Rational
{    
    int num,denum;
    Rational();
    Rational(int a);
    Rational(int a,int b);

    Rational operator+(Rational r){
    Rational h;
    h.num = (num*r.denum + denum*r.num);
    h.denum = (denum*r.denum);
    h.reduce();
    return h;
    }

    Rational operator+(int x){
    Rational h;
    h.num = num + x*denum;
    h.denum = denum;
    h.reduce();
    return h;
    }
};
```

I want to overload the `+` operator for two states: first for addition of a Rational number to an integer number; and second for addition of a Rational number to another Rational number. How can I do this?

Comment: Implement [`__add__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) then check the type of `other`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only provide one definition of `__add__` for your `Rational` class; that function will have to look at the type of its other argument to do the right thing. For example:

```
class Rational(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Rational):
            d = self.b * other.b
            return Rational(self.a * other.b + other.b * self.a, d)
        elif isinstance(other, int):
            return Rational(self.a + self.b * other, self.b)
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    # __add__ is invoked for Rational + other
    # __radd__ will be called by other + Rational if other doesn't
    # know about your class.
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)
```

Comment: Do **not** raise an exception! You **return** a singleton, `NotImplemented`.

Comment: I thought that was just for rich comparison operators?

Comment: OK, looks like the docs were (finally?) updated in 3.4 to mention its use with other operators as well.

Comment: This has always been the case, I don't think the documentation has changed in this respect. In [Python 2.0](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/numeric-types.html) `None` was used instead but that made it impossible for such an operation to produce `None`.

Comment: I had only done a quick check for the constant itself, and https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/constants.html is the first version of this page that mentions operators other than comparison operators.

Comment: In Python 2.2 there was a [separate coercion rules section](https://docs.python.org/2.2/ref/coercion-rules.html) that explains  to return `NotImplemented`.

Comment: (You can probably infer how often I've actually implemented these methods in practice.)

Comment: The coercion section exists from 2.2 (which added the object) until 2.5. 2.6 saw the documentation reworked into the modern format, and the object is right there in the [relevant section for numeric types](https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Answer (score 2):

Python delegates operator handling to the objects involved in the operator. See the [*Emulating numeric types* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) in the Python datamodel documentation.

For the `+` operator, provide an [`__add__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__), and / or  implement the [`__radd__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) if you want to support adding your custom type to an existing type (such as `5 + Rational()`).  Do pay attention to how you handle the 'operation not supported' case; you *return* a singleton `NotImplemented` object, don't raise an exception.